# Casting a generic type in c#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, generic-collections

I have a structure like below. I have some trouble returning a generic collection. What am I missing ?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
          BusinessCollection businessCollection = new BusinessCollection();

          //Why this is not working because businesscollection is a GenericCollection<BusinessEntity>
          businessCollection = new GenericCollection<BusinessEntity>();

          //or neither this
         businessCollection = (BusinessCollection)new GenericCollection<BusinessEntity>();
    }
}



public class BusinessEntity
{
   public string Foo { get; set;}
}

public class BusinessCollection : GenericCollection<BusinessEntity>
{
     //some implementation here
}

public class GenericCollection<T> : ICollection<T>
{
    //some implementation here
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do what you want to do. The other way around will work.

All `BusinessCollection` are indeed `GenericCollection<BusinessEntity>` but you can't say for sure that all `GenericCollection<BusinessEntity>` are `BusinessCollection`'s

So the following will work.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
          GenericCollection<BusinessEntity> businessCollection = new BusinessCollection();
          //this will work
          BusinessCollection tempCollection = (BusinessCollection)businessCollection ;
    }
}



public class BusinessEntity
{
   public string Foo { get; set;}
}

public class BusinessCollection : GenericCollection<BusinessEntity>
{
     //some implementation here
}

public class GenericCollection<T> : ICollection<T>
{
    //some implementation here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your assumptions:

`businesscollection is a GenericCollection<BusinessEntity>`

Yes, but you declared it as type `Businesscollection`. Not all `GenericCollection<BusinessEntity>` are `BusinessCollection` but that's what you're trying to assign to a `BusinessCollection`.

Answer (score 2):

Because a square is a rectangle but not all rectangles are squares.  In this case, a `BusinessCollection` is a `GenericCollection<BusinessEntity>`, but not all `GenericCollection<BusinessEntity>` objects are `BusinessCollection` objects.  A variable typed as a `BusinessCollection` can point to a `GenericCollection<BusinessEntity>` object, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

`businessCollections` is typed as `BusinessCollection`; it can **only** be assigned something that **is** a `BusinessCollection`. However, `GenericCollection<BusinessEntity>()` *is not* a `BusinessCollection`. In the same way that "an animal" is not "a dog" (but "a dog" is "an animal").

This can be validated at runtime or compile-time. The runtime-option is your cast:

```
businessCollection = (BusinessCollection){some expression};
```

this is using the "an animal" *might* be "a dog" test, i.e. check to see whether the particular animal we are considering actually *is* a dog. It defers this check until runtime. Which is why this line *compiles*, but doesn't actually *run*. The particular animal **never** is actually a dog.